# P5.js methods not available in global context when using p5.js with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, p5.js

When trying to adapt p5 to react-p5 following example from p5.js docs, I am able to set up a simple sketch with two setup & draw methods.

When trying to setup a more complex example, with some entity shown in p5.js canvas, I need p5.js methods to draw it in the canvas.

Following the tutorial for react-p5, it [says](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/integrating-p5-sketches-into-your-react-app-de44a8c74e91) :

> If you need the P5 instance used by react-p5 outside your Sketch methods, then you can get it from window.p5.

Here the behavior is surprising : When I try to access p5 global instance, I can access some methods, as `window.p5.Vector.random2D()` but some methods are not available, as `window.p5.stroke(_, _);`. While `window.p5` instance as the same type of `p5` instance passed as an argument in the draw and setup functions of the sketch.

My Question is : How to get a full instance available globally ? I would need this to draw my particle. For now I have access to a global instance of P5 but it does not satifies all the needs.

Here is a working example of the [sketch with stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-dr5dvl?file=package.json,src%2FParticlesSketch.tsx)

[image: js error]

Here is the code involved :

```
import React from "react";
import Sketch from "react-p5";
import p5Types, { Vector } from "p5"; 

class Particle {
    acceleration: Vector;
    velocity: Vector;
    position: Vector;
    lifespan : number;

    constructor(position : Vector) {
        // window.p5.Vector.random2D method is accessible
        this.acceleration = window.p5.Vector.random2D();
        this.velocity = window.p5.Vector.random2D();
        this.position = position.copy();
        this.lifespan = 255;
    }

    update() {
        this.velocity.add(this.acceleration);
        this.position.add(this.velocity);
        this.lifespan -= 2;
    }

    display() {
        // the four methods below are not accessible from p5 instance
        window.p5.stroke(200, this.lifespan);
        window.p5.strokeWeight(2);
        window.p5.fill(127, this.lifespan);
        window.p5.ellipse(this.position.x, this.position.y, 12, 12);
    }

    run() {
        this.update();
        this.display();
    }

    isDead() {
        return this.lifespan < 0;
    }
}


let particle : Particle;

function setup(p5: p5Types, canvasParentRef: Element) {
  p5.createCanvas(720, 400).parent(canvasParentRef);
  particle = new Particle(p5.createVector(50,50));
}

function draw(p5 : p5Types) {
  p5.background(51);
  particle.display();
}

export const ParticlesSketch: React.FC<{}> = () => {

  return <Sketch setup={setup} draw={draw} />;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `react-p5` library isn't intended to be used this way. Instanced p5 methods like `stroke` and `ellipse` should be called on the instance passed to your `draw` or `setup` functions. The guidance you cite about accessing globals using `window.p5` probably refers to types like `p5.Vector` not to drawing methods.

```
import React from 'react';
import Sketch from 'react-p5';
import p5Types, { Vector } from 'p5';

class Particle {
  acceleration: Vector;
  velocity: Vector;
  position: Vector;
  lifespan: number;

  constructor(position: Vector) {
    this.acceleration = Vector.random2D();
    this.velocity = Vector.random2D();
    this.position = position.copy();
    this.lifespan = 255;
  }

  update() {
    this.velocity.add(this.acceleration);
    this.position.add(this.velocity);
    this.lifespan -= 2;
  }

  display(p: p5Types) {
    p.stroke(200, this.lifespan);
    p.strokeWeight(2);
    p.fill(127, this.lifespan);
    p.ellipse(this.position.x, this.position.y, 12, 12);
  }

  run(p: p5Types) {
    this.update();
    this.display(p);
  }

  isDead() {
    return this.lifespan < 0;
  }
}

let particle: Particle;

function setup(p: p5Types, canvasParentRef: Element) {
  p.createCanvas(720, 400).parent(canvasParentRef);
  particle = new Particle(p.createVector(50, 50));
}

function draw(p: p5Types) {
  p.background(51);
  particle.display(p);
}

export const ParticlesSketch: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  return <Sketch setup={setup} draw={draw} />;
};
```

That being said you could theoretically get it to work with something hacky like this:

```
function setup(p: p5Types, canvasParentRef: Element) {
  p.createCanvas(720, 400).parent(canvasParentRef);
  particle = new Particle(p.createVector(50, 50));
  // pure haxin
  // expose all p5.js methods and fields on window (may break things/have unintended consequences)
  const members: any = {};
  for (const key of Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(p))) {
    const member = p[key];
    if (typeof member === 'function') {
      members[key] = member.bind(p);
    } else {
      members[key] = member;
    }
  }
  Object.assign(window, members);
}
```

coupled with this type declaration at the top of your file:

```
declare global {
  interface Window extends p5Types {}
}
```

Comment: the hacky works https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-dr5dvl
you need to resolve types in order to make the compiler not complaining `const member = p5[key as keyof p5Types];`
thank you